# SumIfs with array argument

Tags: excel, vba

Does anybody know how to translate the the following in to excel VBA?

```
SUM(SUMIFS(Sheet3!H:H, Sheet3!G:G, {"X","Y","Z"}, Sheet3!E:E,"SA"))
```

I tried

```
WorksheetFunction.Sum(WorksheetFunction.Sumifs(Worksheet("Sheet3!").Range("H:H"),Worksheet("Sheet3!").Range("G:G"), WorksheetFunction.OR("X","Y","Z"),Worksheet("Sheet3!").Range("E:E"),"SA"))
```

OR

```
WorksheetFunction.Sum(WorksheetFunction.Sumifs(Worksheet("Sheet3!").Range("H:H"),Worksheet("Sheet3!").Range("G:G"), "X" or "Y" or "Z",Worksheet("Sheet3!").Range("E:E"),"SA"))
```

but I wither get

> Type not match error

or

> there is no excel function

OR....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to late bind it:

```
=Application.SumProduct(Application.SumIfs(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("H:H"),Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("G:G"), Array("X","Y","Z"),Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E:E"),"SA"))
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought SumProduct() is to multiply each element across the column then added up. But my intention was just find the valuation that has condition = "x", "y","z" separately then sum up the value... Hopefully it makes sense. By they I did get my desired value base on the code you help me modify. I am just confused a bit . Thank you so much though

Comment: @Daniel the second criterion is optional with SUMPRODUCT and is a way to do Array Sums naturally and must be used in this instance as SUM would return only the first as one cannot array enter a worksheetfunction.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If this worked for you please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Based on Scott's answer. I guess "Sum" works too in replacement of "Sumproduct". Also I would replace "Worksheet" keyword with "Sheets" because it gave me a compile error on my end.

Comment: Application.Sum(Application.SumIfs(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("H:H"), Sheets("Sheet3").Range("G:G"), Array("X", "Y", "Z"), Sheets("Sheet3").Range("E:E"), "SA"))

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. What is today I have two set of array inside of the function. i.e.=Application.SumProduct(Application.SumIfs(Worksheet("Sheet3").Range("H:H"),Worksheet("Sheet3").Range("G:G"), Array("X","Y","Z"),Worksheet("Sheet3").Range("E:E"),Array("SA","SB"))) it does not seem to be the sum when you only have "SA' and "SB"

Comment: use `Application.Transpose(Array())` on one of the arrays.  Also please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  This method BTW can only do two arrays, it is the limit.

Comment: Thank you, just did

Answer (score 0):

let's try:
in Excel

```
=SumProduct(H:H*(E:E="SA")*(Substitute("XYZ",G:G,"") <>"XYZ"))
```

In vba

```
=Evaluate("=SumProduct(H:H*(E:E =""SA"")*(Substitute(""XYZ"",G:G,"""") <>""XYZ""))")
```

oR:

```
=Evaluate("=SUM(SUMIFS(H:H, E:E,""SA"", G:G, {""X"",""Y"",""Z""}))")
```

I recommend that you set a minimum range, not putting an entire column will make the formula run slower and remember SUBSTITUTE is case-sensitive

Comment: The you GridLock, can the Evaluate() take multiple array instead of just  two?