# attempting to total worksheet.sumif with filtered data

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have an excel VBA macro I am working on.  I have the sumif working correctly however I am trying to filter the data and the sumif still adds in the hidden cells.  I have tried a variety of work arounds but am either getting the syntax wrong, or I am just plain missing something simple. What I want is for the WorksheetFunction.Sumif to total just the visible cells.  I am assuming there is something I need to add that tells it to ignore the hidden cells.  Here is a snap of the code in question:

```
' TOTAL THE QUANTITY, COST AND SALE FOR EACH ADVISOR
For Each r In Range("T2", Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Sheets("data").Select
    'ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AUTOFILTER Field:=1, Criteria1:=r
    With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$1")
    .AUTOFILTER Field:=1, Criteria1:=r
    .AUTOFILTER Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "5741", "WW16K", "WW36K", "WW96K", "WW27K", "WW12K", "8056"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End With
    Sheets("template").Select
    r.Offset(, 1) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sht2.Range("A:A"), r, Sht2.Range("B:B"))
    r.Offset(, 2) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sht2.Range("A:A"), r, Sht2.Range("C:C"))
    r.Offset(, 3) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sht2.Range("A:A"), r, Sht2.Range("D:D"))
Next r
    Selection.AUTOFILTER
```

Comment: `r.Offset(, 1) = application.SumProduct(Application.SumIfs(Sht2.Range("B:B"),Sht2.Range("A:A"), r, Sht2.Range("G:G"),Array( "5741", "WW16K", "WW36K", "WW96K", "WW27K", "WW12K", "8056"))`

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59725498/sumifs-with-array-argument

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you so much, I would never have come up with that.  It works perfectly!